# Get total custom dimensions

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I'm trying to get the total costume dimensions used in the session but I'm getting the following error. How can I fix this

```
select count(hits.product.customDimensions.value)
FROM `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_xxxx`,
UNNEST(hits) AS hits,
UNNEST(hits.product) AS prod,
UNNEST(hits.product.customDimensions) AS cust
```

I'm getting the following error

`Cannot access field customDimensions on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT<productSKU STRING, v2ProductName STRING, v2ProductCategory STRING, ...>> at [5:21]`

Comment: Just try cust.value inside count fn.

Comment: @Mr.Batra adding `select count(cust.value)` as suggested still returns the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below

```
select count(cust.value)
FROM `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20170801`,
UNNEST(hits) AS hits,
UNNEST(hits.product) AS prod,
UNNEST(prod.customDimensions) AS cust
```

Comment: One question is a bit unrelated. I'm supposed to quarry for the date  (2017-08-01 4)  what does the 4 mean in this context

Comment: you should replace `20170801` with whatever date you are interested in